# Binding function with argument as derived class

Tags: c++, function, c++11

I am trying to bind `std::function` with derived argument. Function I want to bind looks like this:

```
void Application::myFunction(Derived *derived) { }
```

Function I am trying to pass into this function (but bound) looks like this:

```
void Storage::register(int number, std::function<void(Base *base)>) { }
```

And I am doing this (`this` keyword in this context is `Application`):

```
myStorage->register(0, std::bind(&Application::myFunction, this, std::placeholders::_1);
```

But that gives me error:

> error: no matching function for call (Storage::register...)

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: As presented, the design is incorrect. Say the result of your bind operation is called with a `Base*` that isn't a `Derived*`. This would be equivalent to called `Application::myFunction` with a `Base*` which will not always make sense. So, what are you trying to do exactly? Why isn't this an issue for your use-case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not work because `std::function<void(Base*)>` does not guarantee that it will always be called with a `Derived*`. You cannot do this anymore than you can call `Application::myFunction` with a `Base*` directly.

Depending on what it is you want to achieve, make it a `std::function<void(Derived *)>` or have `myFunction` work with `Base*`.

Comment: Can't make it std::function<void(Derived *)> because there are more(about 10-15 derivations of that class)

Comment: But that is precisely the problem. If you store a function that accepts `Derived*` in a place that will be fed with pointers to objects of any of the other derived classes, you would end up calling that function with pointers to object that are not of `Derived`, and things would explode. You will probably have to give `Base` a sufficient interface that `myFunction` can work with it regardless of which specific derived class the object it works with belongs to (which is what the second option entails).

Comment: It was not problem when I was casting C like function pointers. Just these C++11 template-like wraps.

Comment: If you want to beat the compiler into submission, you can bind to `(void(Application::*)(Base*)) &Application::myFunction`, but doing so is a horrible idea that will break in confusing and difficult-to-debug ways. It is precisely as horrible as beating the compiler into submission by casting normal function pointers in this fashion.

Comment: @Gelidus: What do you mean that it worked when you were *casting C like function pointers*? I am not sure what you mean, but it could be very well that you were running into undefined behavior that happened to seem to work. `void (*p)(Base*) = &f;` where the declaration of `f` is: `void f(Derived *)` should not compile, you can force through a C cast (or `reinterpret_cast`) but forcing the compiler through casts does not make the code better/correct.