# Application design for callbacks with derived classes

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to design application with callbacks which arguments vary. There is one central class `Application` which defines all callbacks. Then there is class `Connection`, which should store those callbacks (already bound).

`Application` looks like this:

```
class Application {

public:
  void firstCallback(DerivedFrist *obj) { }
  void secondCallback(DerivedSecond *obj) { }
};
```

Then there is this `Connection` class which should store registered callbacks and call them when some internal event fires.

```
class Connection {

private:
  map<int, ??> callbacks; // what to do if I want it to be typesafe?
public:
  void registerCallback(int condition, Callback callback) {
    callbacks[condition] = callback;
  }

  void fireCallback(int condition, Base *obj) {
    callbacks[condition](obj); // call the callback from the map (with base object?)
  }
};
```

DerivedFirst and DerivedSecond instances are both created by the internal factory. The factory stores actual types which should be provided to the functions via `Type<D>` class. Map in the factory consists of `condition` and `Type<Base>` ( `map<int, Type<Base>>` )

`Type<D>` class provides simple API: allocate - creates new instance of the type, cast - casts the created instance to the correct type.

Factory code then looks like this:

```
Base *base = this->factoryMap[condition]->allocate();
```

The object is then passed as a derived object (after cast)

**Question:**

This is my approach to the application, which leads to errors when trying to implement with std::function due to type differention. I may reinterpret cast the arguments but that may lead to undefined behaviour.

Is there any good approach to do this? Any patterns are welcome. Thank you!

EDIT : [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27651154/binding-function-with-argument-as-derived-class) previously asked by OP provides more information about the intended design.

Comment: What should `DerivedFirst`, `DerivedSecond` be _derived_ from? What's `Callback` supposed to be? Your question is completely unclear, and havinng s.th. like `firstCallback`, `secondCallback` looks like a completely flawed design for me.

Comment: Does the `Application::*callback` function called depend on the runtime type of the object contained in the `Base* obj`(in `Connection`)? Are you trying to achieve something like the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)?

Comment: `std::function<void(Base *)>` what's wrong with that?

Comment: @user9000 [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27651154/binding-function-with-argument-as-derived-class) will give you context.

Comment: @Pradhan that's also my question, but not so complex

Comment: @Gelidus Could you rephrase please? I am not sure what you meant as an answer to my question.

Comment: @Pradhan Oh sorry, that was not reply to me, nvm then. Trying to look at the visitor pattern now.

Comment: How exactly are `Connection` and `Application` related to each other?

Comment: @jxh Application owns Connection. Connection stores callbacks that are called within the context of Application.

Comment: @jxh That's the question :) Also look at the Pradhan link to see my other question (related also to this)

Comment: Suppose there is only a single derived. Where is `Connection` getting the object to pass into the callback function?

Comment: It's constructed by internal factory

Comment: Can you show a code example of that in your question?

Comment: @Pradhan Ah well, his code pretty much looks like bad design, he should work on that.

Comment: @user9000 `Is there any good approach to do this? `

Answer (score 1):

Since you use a factory method to create a different `Base` for each `condition`, you can modify `Base` to also provide the abstract callback interface.

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void callback(Application *) = 0;
};
```

You can then invoke the callback virtual method on what was returned from the factory for that condition.

Your `Connection` definition was incomplete. Assuming that `callback` held pointers to methods in `Application`, then the callback method could only be invoked if an `Application` instance was supplied.

If we assume that `Connection` must contain a way to register an `Application` instance, then an `Application` could look like this:

```
class Application {

    template <typename DERIVED>
    class Factory {
        Base * allocate () { return new DERIVED; }
        //...
    };

    class DerivedFirst : public Base {
        //...
        void callback(Application *) { /* ... */ }
    };

    class DerivedSecond : public Base {
        //...
        void callback(Application *) { /* ... */ }
    };

};
```

So, `first_condition` is mapped to `Application::Factory<Application::DerivedFirst>`, and `second_condition` is mapped to `Application::Factory<Application::DerivedSecond>`.

In this case, there is no need to register callbacks. They are implicit with the factory generated `Base` object. A `Connection` merely needs to invoke it, passing in the registered `Application`:

```
class Connection {
    Application *app;
public:
    void registerApplication (Application *a) { app = a; }
    void fireCallback (Base *obj) { obj->callback(app); }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
class Base;
class DerivedFirst: public Base { ... };
class DerivedSecond: public Base { ... };
```

You could do:

```
class Connection
{
    typedef std::function<void (Base*)> Callback;

    std::map<int, Callback> callbacks;
    ...
}
```

Then use `std::bind` to bind object member functions, eg:

```
Application application;
Connection connection;

connection.registerCallback(42, std::bind(&Application::firstCallback, &application, std::placeholders::_1);
```